# How to flatten Array of WrappedArray?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have tied various Stackoverflow question but unable to get to the end goal of a array of distinct values from the DataFrame.

```
val df = Seq(
  List("Mandrin","Hindi","English"),
  List("French","English")
).toDF("languages")

df.collect.map(_.toSeq).flatten
```

Returns

```
Array[Any] = Array(WrappedArray(Mandrin, Hindi, English), WrappedArray(French, English))
```

Desired result is

```
Array(Mandrin, Hindi, English, French)
```

If I could get it to a flat array with duplicates, then I can call distinct.

thanks.

Comment: `...).flatten.distinct.toDF(...`

Answer (score 2):

You don't need that additional map step, when you collect you already have a list of sequences of string. You just need to flatten them to get an Array of Strings.

```
val languagesArray:Array[String] = df.collect().flatten
```

However when working with huge sets of data it is not often the best idea to collect the data, maybe you can consider using explode

```
  import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
  df.select(explode($"languages")).show()
```

this generates the following output

```
+-------+
|    col|
+-------+
|Mandrin|
|  Hindi|
|English|
| French|
|English|
+-------+
```

on either of the output you can then do a `distinct` to get the distinct languages.

Comment: I have tried using flattern directly like "df.collect.flatten" but I get error "error: No implicit view available from org.apache.spark.sql.Row => Traversable[U].".
"df.select(explode($"languages")).show()" works so I will go with it. ie."val languages = df.select(explode($"languages")).distinct.collect" Thanks.

Comment: This worked to get an array of strings.  "df.select(explode($"languages")).distinct.map(row => row.mkString).collect"